# Help translating writing on a bowl

Tags: translation, characters

[image]

Hi there! Could anybody translate what is written on the bottom of this bowl? It is at the request of an elderly relative who is computer illiterate! Many thanks!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Chinese SE. Unfortunately, this site is not a transliteration or translation service, unless the question shows some effort. Please show us what you have attempted in identifying the characters, or this question may be closed as being off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“大明年造”
“Made in the Ming Dynasty”